# How do I generate test reports from Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a test project running successfully on Jenkins using Ant. I see the test results in the console output but how do I generate a report?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use Jenkins and Espresso also. I use [Spoon by Jake Wharton](https://github.com/square/spoon) to generate my reports. Take a look! They are clean and very easy to use.

Comment: This is what i ended up doing. I love the spoon reports. Thanks!

Comment: @Binghammer: Have you been able to trigger a Jenkins build failure when a Spoon test failure occurs? Do you have to manually parse the spoon result.json file?

Comment: @PeterTran it has been a minute since I have ran any automated tests. However, if I remember correctly, Jenkins should notice the error generated by spoon and report it as such. As for parsing results, this was my best solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827743/how-to-order-test-cases-for-spoon-automated-testing-in-android/24065233#24065233

Answer (score 0):

Without using Espresso this can be done easily by using the [JUnitReportTestRunner](https://github.com/jsankey/android-junit-report/) from Zutubi. The report can then be digested e.g. via the [Jenkins xUnit Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin)

Espresso though requires its own testrunner that has to be based on [GoogleInstrumentation](http://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/source/browse/testrunner/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/common/testing/testrunner/GoogleInstrumentation.java). Combining both the JUnitReportTestRunner and the GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner is quite hacky at the moment, because GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner does not expose a method to attach a test listener. [This google groups post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-test-kit-discuss/_Lu3odqITj0/I-GAIjXBxz0J) shows how to attach the listener from the Zutubi project anyway.